# How do I will Be able to play the video when the link is already appended as a child in card

Tags: javascript, html

```
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Welcome</h1>
    <h4>Get A Free Video Answer For Your Question</h4>
    <input class="question_input" type="text" placeholder="write your question here" />
    <button class="button" type="submit" onclick="submit_question()">submit</button>
    <div class="container"></div>

    <script>
        function submit_question(){
            const Ans_value = document.querySelector('.question_input').value;
            //send to server
            fetch('http://localhost:3000/answers', { 
                method:'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({Ans_value})
            })
        }
        function newEl(type, attrs={}){
            const el = document.createElement(type);
            for (let attr in attrs ){
                const value = attrs[attr];

                if (attr == 'innerText') el.innerText= value;
                else el.setAttribute(attr, value);
            }
            return el;
        } 
        async function Loadanswers(){
            const res = await fetch('http://localhost:3000/answers');
            const answers = await res.json();

            const ctr = document.querySelector('.container'); 

            answers.forEach(answer => {
                const card = newEl('div', {class: 'card'});
                const searchresults_quant = newEl('h4',{innerText: answer.searchresults_quant});
                const searchresultsq_title = newEl('h4', {innerText: answer.searchresultsq_title}); //const img = newEl('img', {src: answer.img});
                const searchresultsq1 = newEl('h4', {innerText: answer.searchresultsq1});       
                const Q_url1 = newEl('img', {src: answer.Q_url1});
                //Q_url1.style.width = '600px';
                card.appendChild(searchresults_quant);
                card.appendChild(searchresultsq_title);
                card.appendChild(searchresultsq1);
                card.appendChild(Q_url1);
                


                //const a = document.querySelector('a');                                                                                                        



                ctr.appendChild(card);
            })  
        }    
        Loadanswers();
    
    </script>
    <style>
        .button{
            float: left;
            width: 20%;
            padding: 10px;
            background: #2196F3;
            color: white;
            font-size: 17px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            border-left: none; /* Prevent double borders */
            cursor: pointer;
        }
        .question_input{
            display: block;
            padding: 10px;
            font-size: 17px;
            border: 1px solid grey;
            float: left;
            width: 80%;
            background: #f1f1f1;
            
        }
        .container{
           display: table-caption;
        }
        .card{
            margin: 10px;
            padding: 300px;
            background-color: rgb(191, 191, 245);
            box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(231, 10, 10, 0.2);
            transition: 0.3s;
            width: 50%;
            height: 25%;
        }
    </style>

</body>
```

is there anyone please who can solve this for me! thanks in advance.

`card.appendChild(searchresults_quant);` => these are the questions quantity shown as a number in the              same card from my cloud database.

`card.appendChild(searchresultsq_title);` => these are the questions titles from also from cloud database

`card.appendChild(searchresultsq1);` => these are the results fetched also from cloud database and shown in same card.

`card.appendChild(Q_url1);` => this url is fetched from the cloud database and the problem is here this is a **webm** but it is shown as an *image* so i need to show it as a video so once someone wants to watch it, they can but it'll be in the same card below the (searchresultsq1).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `const Q_url1 = newEl('img', {src: answer.Q_url1});`, based on your function creates an **img** element. Try the following :

```
const video = newEl('video', {width: '400', controls: ''});
const source = newEl('source', {src: answer.Q_url1, type: 'video/mp4'});
video.appendChild(source);
...
card.appendChild(video); //instead of card.appendChild(Q_url1);
....
```